# Jupyter Notebook, file size is showing 0B, so basically my notebook is gone, can I retrieve it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So going back to do some work on a Jupyter Notebook but get an error message when I try to open it: Error loading notebook
Permission denied: my_jn_notebook.ipynb

I then see the size of the notebook is now 0B.

My questions are:
Why and how did this happen?

Is there ANY none to complicated way to get my notebook back?
(I can re-write it but want to save myself from quite a few hours of work)

How do I prevent this from happening in the future other than not using Jupyter Notebook which is likely what I will do.

Thanks.

Comment: We cannot really tell you when or how your notebook shrunk or lost data. That is entirely up to you and your data safety and backup procedures. The answer to your second question, how to prevent it from happening again, is the same: You are responsible for backing up your data, regardless of whether the Jupyter data is "cloud" or not.

Comment: Possibly worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819322/how-to-recover-deleted-ipython-notebooks

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that it had add

Comment: Thanks for the adivice. I figured out that it had saved the file with a .~ prefix and that was not visible in the browser directory (ie within jupyter notebook) but it was visible in the file directory so after removing that weird prefix I could access my work again.